# MYSQLi Creates Database with ? as name

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I wrote an Install File for my own CMS which I'm working atm. I changed the SQL statements to make it a bit saver but now nothing works and I can't figure out why...

I change my code from:

```
$db = new mysqli($_POST['db_ip'], $_POST['db_user'], $_POST['db_key'], '', $_POST['db_port']);
if(!$db) {
    exit('Connection error to database');
}
$query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $db_name;";
$ergebnis = mysqli_query($db, $abfrage);
```

to:

```
$db = new mysqli($_POST['db_ip'], $_POST['db_user'], $_POST['db_key'], '', $_POST['db_port']);
if(!$db) {
    exit('Error connecting to database'); //Should be a message a typical user could understand in production
}
$db_name = $_POST['db_name'];
$query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ?;";
$stmt->bind_param('s', $db_name);
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

I even tried:

```
$db = new mysqli($_POST['db_ip'], $_POST['db_user'], $_POST['db_key'], '', $_POST['db_port']);
if(!$db) {
    exit('Error connecting to database'); //Should be a message a typical user could understand in production
}
$db_name = $_POST['db_name'];
$query = mysqli_prepare "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ?;";
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 's', $db_name);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

last one added me a database but with the ? as name...

I hoped some one here can help me with that.

Comment: What does it mean, "a bit safer"? What danger you are trying to prevent and why?

Comment: I want to avoid overloading the SQL Server.

Comment: what kind of overloading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not every SQL statement supports prepared statements. And CREATE DATABASE is one of them.

So, as a general rule, you are supposed to choose the database/table name from the *white list*.

In your specific case, however, when a user is apparently a **database owner**, there is not much point in protecting them from SQL injection as *they apparently has the database password and can run any SQL statement much more convenient way.* So you changed the code for nought. Just revert it back to the regular `query()`  call.

I would only add `backticks` around the table name so it would always make a correct identifier name. And also may be add a regex validation just in order to avoid a human error.

Comment: ok thanks :) Can you gave me an example if I check the Registering of an user to the website? so for that I should use prepared statements right? I mean the selection isn't the problem with the registration it's the insert command.

Comment: Yes, of course. Not sure what you mean but I've got an example [how to check if a user entered valid username and password using mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/password_hash)

Comment: Thanks I will try it.

Comment: I tried it and it works fine as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland I know so created following user: ```GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'WebAdmin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '<Password>' WITH GRANT OPTION; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `webadmin`.* TO 'WebAdmin'@'%'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `webadmin\_%`.* TO 'WebAdmin'@'%';``` Yea I know he have full power on all Databases and .co but atm the System is running local on my Computer for testing.

Comment: @RyffLe from the installation process perspective you may want to catch an error during the database creation and suggest the site owner to create the database beforehand

Comment: Doesn't make that "IF NOT EXISTS"? *now I am confused* xD

Comment: @RyffLe in case it doesn't exist and there are no permissions to create, there will be an error.